# creation name SSIS.Replacement task is not registered with your computer

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

When i tried to run the .dtsx file i got the following error

> The task with the name "some task" and the creation name
>   "SSIS.ReplacementTask" is not registered for use on this computer

I change the logon to network serivce of Sql Integeration service fron SQL server configuration but still m getting this error please help

Comment: Is that the precise error message or are you summarizing it for us? How are you running the package?

Comment: @billinkc i just opened the package on its first task it is giving this error  and this is not the precise error message i change the task name

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b62a4183-d04a-4cd7-91dc-8836c3a292ec/the-task-with-the-name-and-the-creation-name-is-not-registered-for-use-on-this-computer?forum=sqlintegrationservices).

> When you use username and password to log on to your computer, sql server need to verify the user who authorized to use the sql server service.. But sometimes sql server cannot  redirect to the account, so we need to configure the user.
>   Here's the step :
>   1. open sql server configuration mangager
>   2. choose sql server 2005 services
>   3. right click sql server integration services, choose properties
>   4. choose log on tab, select this account, enter your username and password which is used to log on your computer.
>   5. reopen the business intelligence studio. There you are, the task component can work properly again.

It also might be that this is a custom component which is not installed at your global assembly cache (in case you are not running it at the server to which it was originally deployed).

Comment: this answer will be all but useless if that link ever goes dead.