# Visual Studio 17 and 19 Can No Longer Edit SSIS Projects

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I installed the Enterprise version of Visual Studio 19 about a year ago. That was many months after I installed and was using Visual Studio 17 on a daily basis. I had SQL Server Data Tools installed, too, for VS17 to work on SSIS projects. To make it clear, both VS17 and VS19 were installed on my laptop and were playing nice together. All was fine. I work in a corporate environment. I am unaware of all group policies that may be in force on my laptop. After a recent Windows upgrade, Visual Studio, neither version, can no longer edit tasks in SSIS projects. Also, in SQL Server Management Studio, I can no longer right-click on a database / Tasks / Import Data. I also cannot edit a SQL agent job step. The errors are shown below.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing to no avail. When I re-installed VS19, I installed the extension SQL Server 2019 Integration Services to work with SSIS projects. Not only did I uninstall the products listed above, but also a host of associated programs like redistributables, SQL Server drivers, etc. Our help desk gave me a clean Windows install. I installed VS19 with the extension, and at first, I was not receiving the error. I shut down my machine. When I rebooted in the morning, and connected to the company's VPN, the problem seemed to resurface. Reading this, I see I am giving the wrong impression - implying that something is amiss in the company's group policies. My feeling is that the problem is with the VS19 extension. Here are the errors.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im6N3.jpg)

[image: Another]

[image: Third]

[image: Last]

Comment: This sounds like you've really broken something on you host. The fact that multiple applications are failing suggest you've deleted something you should not have.

Comment: The errors occurred right after a fresh install, as was clearly stated in the description, "<i>Our help desk gave me a clean Windows install. I installed VS19 with the extension, and at first, I was not receiving the error. I shut down my machine. When I rebooted in the morning, and connected to the company's VPN, the problem seemed to resurface.</>"

Answer (score 0):

Probably these two answers might help you:

- [creation name SSIS.Replacement task is not registered with your computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430635/creation-name-ssis-replacement-task-is-not-registered-with-your-computer)
- [SSIS custom task is not registered for use on this computer error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658542/ssis-custom-task-is-not-registered-for-use-on-this-computer-error)

Comment: To be clear, I am running CLIENT software on a laptop. I do not have an instance of SQL Server running locally.